# Pattern to check if a string contains specific characters

Tags: java, regex, string

Honestly, I don't know much about patterns, but I need one to let me know if one of more of these and only these characters exists in `myString`.

```
String myString = "thisMayContain/anything@";
String charactersIdontWant = "^àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ!&{}¿?.<>~\()";
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`String.indexOf(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29) to check if a specific character is in your string or not (it will return -1 if it's not in it).

You can use [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) to get an array of all the characters you don't want and iterate this array per character.

Readable and simple code (though not most efficient) will be:

```
private static boolean charsOK(String s) { 
    String charactersIdontWant = "^àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ!&{}¿?.<>~\\()";
    for (char c : charactersIdontWant.toCharArray()) {
        if (s.indexOf(c) != -1) return false;
    }
    return true;

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myString = "thisMayContïain/anything@";
    String myString2 = "thisMayContain/anything@";
    System.out.println(charsOK(myString));
    System.out.println(charsOK(myString2));
}
```

Comment: Yes, maybe this is not the most efficient way to do it, but it works perfect for what i want. I tried the pvgoran's pattern, but don't work for some reasons, maybe because my own ignorance, also and maybe for the same reason, I could'n import the StringUtils library to my android project. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use containsAny() from Apache's StringUtils:

```
boolean haveBadCharacters = StringUtils.containsAny(myString, charactersIdontWant);
```

If you insist on a pattern, you can use:

```
Pattern badCharactersPattern = Pattern.compile("[àáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ!&{}¿?.<>~\()^]");
```

(Note that `^` is moved to the end so that it isn't interpreted as group negation indicator.)

Answer (score 1):

Stop reinventing the wheel.  [Apache Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) solved this problem years ago.  Goto the api page (follow the link) and look for *containsAny*.